# Postman - How to replace values for all specific properties in the JSON Response, to use it later as another Request's Body

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have 2 API requests. 1st one is GET, that returns a response. This response is used as a Body/Payload in the 2nd request (POST). BUT the Payload should have certain values to be replaced before used in the 2nd request (in my case below it should be value for "Status" property).

How can I do it?

Here is my example Response:

```
{  
   "Variations":[  
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "xxx"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V1",
               "GuId":"xxx",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 1",
         "Id":"67-V1"
      },
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "yyy"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V2",
               "GuId":"yyy",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 2",
         "Id":"67-V2"
      },
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "zzz"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V3",
               "GuId":"zzz",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 3",
         "Id":"67-V3"
      }
   ],
   "ItemIds":[  

   ],
   "Items":[  

   ],
   "Name":"MAINP",
   "Id":"67",
   "Color":null
}
```

Here is my code, but it does not seem to work (the replacement part):

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

function replaceStatus() {
    _.each(jsonData.Variations, (arrayItem) => {
        if(arrayItem.Items.Status !== "NonActive") {

            arrayItem.Items.Status == "NonActive";
            console.log("arrayItem " + arrayItem);
        }
    });
}

pm.test("Run Function", replaceStatus ());

pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'localhost:3000/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to replace all `NonActive` values with `Active`. In that case, you should use `=` for assignment not `==`. The JSON file you provided is not valid and couldn't run your code on my machine. I am happy to have a closer look if that didn't work

**Based on your updates these changes need to be made**

1- in order to deal with JSON object you need to parse the response as it is `string` and you can't call sth like `JsonData.Variations` on that.make sure `jsonData` is a JSON object. if not add sth like this to parse it

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonData)
```

2- It seems that you missed one array layer in your function to iterate over `items`. As you have two nested arrays to reach `Status` the `replaceStatus` function should be as below

```
function replaceStatus() {
    _.each(parsedJson.Variations, (arrayItem) => {
        _.each(arrayItem.Items, (item) => {
            if(item.Status !== "NonActive") {
                item.Status = "NonActive";
                console.log("arrayItem " + item.Status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehran! I have corrected the Response JSON (in the original message). And I also tried with "=" instead of "==". But seems like it's still not working.OR may be I'm not doing it right. I.e. I do not see this line to output into the Console - `console.log("arrayItem " + arrayItem);`  Also I'm not sure how to make **updated** jsonData (after the values got replaced).

Comment: @KVN make the JSON is valid by testing it in  an online JSON linter. I am pretty sure the solution works as I tried it on my machine. Also try it without parsing JSON as I suspect ‘.json’ in the first line of your code parse it and you literally parse it two times

Comment: Thanks @Mehran! Yeah seems like the additional parsing was unnecessary. And it seems to work! (P.S. I deleted my last comment, with an idea to post it a bit modified, before I saw your last reply). Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you posted your entire code in the tests section or only a part of it?
I saw from one of your comments that you cannot see the output logged to the console.

This may be very trivial, but, if you did post your entire code, it looks like you may have forgotten to call your `replaceStatus()` function before your post call.

Comment: Thanks @Derryl Thomas for pointing this out. I'm really missing to actually use it :/ Added it now.