# Postman - taking attributes and values from one JSON to create another JSON

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

This in relation to my older ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298735/postman-how-to-replace-values-for-all-specific-properties-in-the-json-response)!
But now I need to get more advanced. I need to get only certain attributes and their values (from the 1st Response JSON) to create another JSON (and some values to be replaced in new JSON).

I.e. in the Response JSON below, I need to go through all "Items" (and I do not know in advance how many those can be), and get only `Id + value`, and `Status+value` for each of them. Then to build another new JSON, where the top attribute will be called `Products` instead of `Variations`, and contain only `Id+value` and `Status+*NewValue*`.

1st Response JSON:

```
   "Variations":[  
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "xxx"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V1",
               "GuId":"xxx",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 1",
         "Id":"67-V1"
      },
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "yyy"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V2",
               "GuId":"yyy",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 2",
         "Id":"67-V2"
      },
      {  
         "ItemIds":[  
            "zzz"
         ],
         "Items":[  
            {  
               "Id":"67-V3",
               "GuId":"zzz",
               "Type":"Unit",
               "Status":"Active"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"VAR 3",
         "Id":"67-V3"
      }
   ],
   "ItemIds":[  

   ],
   "Items":[  

   ],
   "Name":"MAINP",
   "Id":"67",
   "Color":null
}
```

New JSON I would like to create:

```
{  
   "Products":[  
      {  
               "Id":"67-V1",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      },
      {  
               "Id":"67-V2",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      },
      {  
               "Id":"67-V3",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have made following code:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var newData;
var newDataGroup = "";

function replaceValues() {
    _.each(jsonData.Variations, (arrayItem) => {
        _.each(arrayItem.Items, (item) => {
            if(item.Status !== "NonActive") {
                item.Status = "NonActive";
                console.log("arrayItem " + item.Status);
            }
            newData = "{ \"Id\":\"" + item.Id + "\", " +  " \"Status\":\"" + item.Status + "\"},";
            newDataGroup = newDataGroup + newData;
        });
    });
    newDataGroup = "{ \"Products\": [ " + newDataGroup + " ] }";
}
pm.test("Run Replace", replaceValues ());
console.log("newDataGroup Final: " + newDataGroup);
var newJson = JSON.parse(newDataGroup);
console.log("newJson: " + newJson);
```

Here is my outcome (based on the code above), but how to deal with the last `,` there?

```
{  
   "Products":[  
      {  
               "Id":"67-V1",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      },
      {  
               "Id":"67-V2",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      },
      {  
               "Id":"67-V3",
               "Status":"NonActive"
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, I'm all for answering questions that relate to other early things you've asked but this isn't a code writing service. There needs to be a level of research done too.

Comment: Sorry @DannyDainton, missed my code part. Added it now. Not sure if it's correct code from a coding point of view. But getting an error where I would not expect it to be though.

Comment: Hi @DannyDainton, I have made changes to my original code, which seems to address all errors I was getting. The only final issue I have so far is that - the final DataArray will have `,` at the end of it. And I'm not sure how to make either not being added or removed in the final data string.

Comment: Actually solved that one too. With `newDataGroup = newDataGroup.slice(0, -1);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like here is the final code that will do the trick. While most likely, not the most elegant but does the job. If anyone can suggest the more elegant way, would be appreciated.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var newData;
var newDataGroup = "";

function replaceValues() {
    _.each(jsonData.Variations, (arrayItem) => {
        _.each(arrayItem.Items, (item) => {
            if(item.Status !== "NonActive") {
                item.Status = "NonActive";
            }
            newData = "{ \"Id\":\"" + item.Id + "\", " +  " \"Status\":\"" + item.Status + "\"},";
            newDataGroup = newDataGroup + newData;
        });
    });
    newDataGroup = newDataGroup.slice(0, -1);
    newDataGroup = "{ \"Products\": [ " + newDataGroup + " ] }";
}
pm.test("Run Replace", replaceValues ());
var newJson = JSON.parse(newDataGroup);
```